# Azure functions resolving npm packages locally but not in azure

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-functions

I am writing some azure functions using node. I have the following folder structure (note that all dependencies are declared inside a `package.json` that lives in a folder above where the azure functions are located).

```
  |-- package.json
  |-- node_modules /* dependencies for all code in sub-folders lives here */
  |-- server/
      |-- src/
          |-- azf/
              |-- host.json
              |-- local.settings.json
              |-- tsconfig.json
              |-- package.json /* only npm scripts in this file, no dependencies */
              |-- FunctionOne/
                  |-- function.json
                  |-- index.ts
              |-- FunctionTwo/
                  |-- function.json
                  |-- index.ts
```

This set up works fine locally when I run

```
func start
```

but when I deploy these to azure via a github action, the code inside the functions throws errors about not finding dependencies. For example, it's not able to find `lodash` at runtime:

> Failure Exception: Worker was unable to load function FunctionTwo: 'Cannot find > module 'lodash' Require stack: - /home/site/wwwroot/dist/FunctionTwo/index.js

Generally in the node world it's fine to use a dependency that is resolved in the `node_modules` of a parent folder. The node runtime will walk up the directory structure looking through `node_modules` folders until it finds the dependency it's looking for or reaches the root of the file system. This apparently is not working within azure though.

Is it possible to make this work inside azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are likely zipping the `azf` folder and deploying it on azure, and hence the `node_modules` folder is not present leading to no dependencies from being found.

There are two ways you can approach this

**1. Duplicate Dependencies in its `package.json` file**

Since [running as a package](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-trigger?tabs=python-v2%2Cin-process&pivots=programming-language-csharp#blob-receipts) is recommended to prevent cold starts, the `package.json` file for your azure functions should also have its dependencies required to run the functions. This file would only be used during deployment as part of your GitHub Actions workflow where you will install dependencies before zipping to publish your function app.

This has the downside of duplicating the dependencies but in a way is a simpler approach

**2. Bundle your functions**

This is a bit more nuanced since there is no readily available official way to do this. The idea is to use something like webpack to bundle your functions into single files including all dependencies.

There are some implementations ([`funcpack`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-pack) and [`azure-functions-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/PageProofCom/azure-functions-webpack-plugin)) of this which aren't really maintained but could give you an idea on how you can approach them.

While I don't have a readily available webpack config to share, a simple approach would be to

- Have a separate entry point for each function
- Generate `function.json` files with the right `scriptFile` property (Refer this TypeScript section [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=typescript%2Clinux%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v3#registering-a-function))
- Include loaders and plugins for typescript, babel, etc. depending on your use case

Comment: Thank you for the answer, option 1 is what I ended up doing. I am also considering putting the `FunctionOne` and `FunctionTwo` folders at the top level and putting just the `function.json` files them. Each `function.json` file would use the `scriptFile` property to point to the actual source code back in the `server/src/azf` directory. I don't like having those function folders at the top level but at least I could have the actual source code where I want it and I wouldn't have to duplicate the dependencies in multiple `package.json` files. It's frustrating how Microsoft set this up.

Comment: Yes. That should work. It is a workaround indeed to get it to work but this is just because Azure Functions for JS were not designed for monorepos. In the case of C#, this works flawlessly since the code is compiled and output into a separate directory, which is bundled instead.